# Strip tags using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, tags, strip

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#">link</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to: FIND 'link' in 'a' and STRIP ALL parent tags except/until 'table'. I know its not the ideal way to do it, but sometimes you just can't modify the markup so it'd be great to know a jquery hack for this.

Comment: What is your expected markup output?

Comment: <table><a href="#>link</a></table>

Comment: That's not valid HTML. I'm not sure you'll be able to coerce all browsers into producing that invalid DOM.

Comment: @Nimbuz - why not remove the `<table>` too an replace with say, a `<div>`? I'm assuming that you're keeping the table because of positioning/styling?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var a = $("a:contains('link')");
var table = a.closest('table');
a.insertBefore( table );        // Edit: See comments below
table.contents().remove();
table.append( a );
```

Edit: Calling `remove()` will also remove any event handlers that might be attached to the anchor element.  To get around that, move the anchor outside of the table before removing its contents.

Comment: you could also `clone(true)` the `<a>` elements, remove all from `<tr>` downwards and then append the clones.